# Getting errors with pytorch grouped convolutions

Tags: python, pytorch, convolution

I am trying to use Pytorch grouped Conv2d operator on very large images (10k x 10k pixels). I am getting an *RuntimeError: offset is too big* error when trying to apply a grouped convolution in the network. Anyone knows how to circumvent this?

Code for reproducibility:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import pdb


def create_img(size, batch_size=1, channels=3):
    return torch.FloatTensor(batch_size, channels, size, size).uniform_(-1, 1)


class TestModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(1,1), groups=64, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv1(x)
        return out


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = TestModel()

    data = create_img(5002, channels=64)

    out = model(data)
    pdb.set_trace()
```

and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    out = model(data)
  File ".../pipenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 17, in forward
    out = self.conv1(x)
  File ".../pipenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File ".../pipenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 320, in forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
RuntimeError: offset is too big
```

I am using Python 3.6 and Pytorch 1.0.0. Strange thing is, this works with smaller images. Change the images size from 5002 to 502, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating Pytorch to 1.3.0